# Swift: Trying to read swift source code

Tags: swift

I am fairly new to coding and yet I often run into problems, because I lack knowledge. I would like to teach myself by reading swift´s source code, but I either don't know how to read or don't know how to access it.

Easy example: I´d like to know more about - let's say Integers. So I type in Int and command click the button to "Jump to [its] definition".
There I find the following:

```
    public struct Int : FixedWidthInteger, SignedInteger { 
        ..
        public typealias IntegerLiteralType = Int
        ..
        public init(bitPattern x: UInt)
        ..
        public static func *= (lhs: inout Int, rhs: Int)
        ...
```

Some of these methods and functions make perfect sense to me, but many, just like the latter, lack a function body.

**So my question is:** How can I access the definition of e.g. *public static func *= (lhs: inout Int, rhs: Int)* or where can I learn how to read it properly if that one line actually is the whole definition?

Comment: Please read [Swift Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/) and something about object oriented programming.

Comment: I’d also recommend reading Documentation rather than just the function definitions. Although (using your example) Int is possibly a difficult place to start. It’s simplicity of usage belies the complexity underneath it. Have a look at some of the higher level types. Or possibly some of the protocols that one might implement like Equatable or Comparable. Etc... but yes, the Swift Language Guide is also an excellent place to start.

Comment: Just explain the given example to me and I´ll be good. What is _public static func *= (lhs: inout Int, res: Int)_ doing exactly? Where is its function body?

Comment: If you want to ask a *specific* question (such as about the `*=` function) then edit the question and the title accordingly. As it stands, “Swift: Deeper understanding of code - but HOW?” is a far too broad question.

Comment: FYI - when you "jump to its definition" in Xcode, that's not the source code. It's just the interface. If you want the source code then go to the swift.org. But reading the Swift source code is not a good way to learn Swift.

Answer (score 4):

Swift is an open source language, which means all of its implementations are free for you to browse on [Github](https://github.com/apple/swift).

Unfortunately, you picked a really tricky one to start with. There are a number of integer types in Swift, and to manage all the boilerplate that accompanies nearly identical implementations of certain methods across these integer types, Swift uses a tool called `gyb` ([generate your boilerplate](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/utils/gyb.py)). The implementation, nevertheless, can be found in the [stdlib/public/core/Integers.swift.gyb](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Integers.swift.gyb).

Answer (score 1):

> Some of these methods and functions make perfect sense to me, but many, just like the latter, lack a function body.

Correct, because you are looking at the Swift *header* file. It shows declarations, not implementations. It is not the actual source. The source is on github and is mostly not written in Swift.

Similarly for Cocoa in general. You can see header files. The source is closed.

> I would like to teach myself by reading swift´s source cod

Bad plan. Read some Swift code, sure. But not the source of the language itself.

Answer (score -3):

After doing some research with some of the links you gave me, I think that I can now answer the question myself.

There is a lot of functionality implemented in Swift, to which the source code is not published. An example is the framework UIKit. Apple has no interest to share the information about how a lot of these objects are defined and so it should be pretty hard to access their definition.

The general language source code for Swift however is open to the public and can be found and downloaded on GitHub, but you won't be able to publish any applications in the App Store that run with changed source code and there will be a lot of missing puzzle pieces to the Swift you use in xCode. Therefor it is rather helpful if you aim to develop your own language, than it is if you want to gain deeper knowledge about how Swift works. In the end that probably improves the language´s safety, but at the same time makes it harder for people to actually understand and customize Swift.